# How can I add a landing page before GitLab's login page?

Tags: gitlab

Running a GitLab deployed on AMI/AWS. Currently my domain leads straight to the login. How do I add a page such that www.example.com is a custom page, then **www.example.com/GitLab** is Gitlab's login page?

Comment: How did you deploy Gitlab? Omnibus package?

Answer (score 0):

If you deployed Gitlab using omnibus package the procedure is pretty simple :

Set the external_url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:
`external_url "https://example.com/gitlab"`

Reconfigure GitLab for the changes to take effect:
`sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Restart the services so that Unicorn and Sidekiq picks up the changes
`sudo gitlab-ctl restart`

From https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-a-relative-url-for-gitlab

However, if you deployed from the sources then the procedure is described here https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/relative_url.html